# What's the difference in evaluating expression in VAR vs. RETURN in a measure variable?

Tags: powerbi, dax, evaluation

Is there a difference in (OPTION 1) using a VAR to evaluate part of an expression and (OPTION 2) directly evaluating the same expression in the RETURN part of a measure variable.

OPTION 1

```
Test = 
VAR 
    previousperiod = LASTNONBLANK(PREVIOUSMONTH('Customer base'[Date]),1)
RETURN
    CALCULATE(SUM('Customer base'[Count]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Customer base'), 'Customer base'[Date] = previousperiod))
```

OPTION 2

```
Test = 
RETURN
    CALCULATE(SUM('Customer base'[Count]), FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Customer base'), 'Customer base'[Date] = LASTNONBLANK(PREVIOUSMONTH('Customer base'[Date]),1)))
```

Because when I do OPTION 1 I get the result I want, but with OPTION 2 I get all blank values.

Answer (score 1):

Formated option 1 :

```
Test =
VAR previousperiod =
    LASTNONBLANK (
        PREVIOUSMONTH ( 'Customer base'[Date] ),
        1
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Customer base'[Count] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( 'Customer base' ),
            'Customer base'[Date] = previousperiod
        )
    )
```

Formated option 2 :

```
Test =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Customer base'[Count] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'Customer base' ),
        'Customer base'[Date]
            = LASTNONBLANK (
                PREVIOUSMONTH ( 'Customer base'[Date] ),
                1
            )
    )
)
```

Variable are constant and are evaluated once! : 
Evaluation take place at the first use within the evaluation context where it is define.

Therefore in **option 1**, 
VAR previousperiod is defined in Evaluation context store and value is given to the return block

Whereas in **option 2**,

```
LASTNONBLANK (
                PREVIOUSMONTH ( 'Customer base'[Date] ),
                1
            )
```

Is evaluated when it is used, here in the row context of the iteration AllSELECTED('Customer base')